# How do I find out who sent me a WhatsApp picture located in my photo gallery?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

when i look up photos in my gallery, i get interested in few of them, and realize that they were sent on a group via WhatsApp. but how to identify which group and who is the sender?

Comment: You need access to Whatsapp's databases stored in its app directory. If it permits adb backup, you can try to take backup and look into it. Otherwise, you would need root access. Afterwards, search into databases where the media files are referenced. They would probably be referenced through a row_id. It is too much work so I can't post a working answer.

Comment: @Firelord afaik WhatsApp can export chat in txt or xml format, maybe query on that files will work

Comment: @alecxs when exporting chats (with media) the text file of chat history does show the file name of the images along with who sent it. So yeah, that's one and a rather easier (than mine) way to go.